# Find error in this algebraic transformation on a function

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)=x^2+x\sqrt{x^2-1}$. Apparently the statement

> $\forall x$ for which $x,-x\in\mathbb D$, $f(x)=f(-x)$.

is false, but I can “prove” it by
\begin{align}x^2+x\sqrt{x^2-1}=x\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)=\frac x{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac1{1-\sqrt{1-\frac1{x^2}}}.\end{align}
I still don’t see any problems in it.

Comment: What is the set D?

Comment: @Chazg I mean the set on which the function is defined. For the function $f(x)$ defined above, $\mathbb D=(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$

Comment: OK, so $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} | x^{2}\geq1$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In last step, when you "pull out $x$" from the square root, you really should be pulling out $|x|$. Fixing this yields result
$$
\frac 1{  1-\operatorname{sgn}(x) \sqrt{1-\frac 1{x^2}} }.
$$